# Using ngx-stripe and ngx-card together

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I am trying to build a card-information form, which I would like to look something like this[image]

The problem is, I cannot seem to make `ngx-card` work well with `ngx-stripe`.

The problem is, in order to use the card animation package, I absolutely have to know what is being inserted in each of the inputs, but I can't find any way to get that information from Stripe Elements.

I've also tried using basic inputs instead of Stripe Elements, and they work perfectly with `ngx-card`, but I cannot use then with Stripe, as none of the overloads of the `createToken` function of the `StripeService` accepts as parameters anything but Stripe Elements.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

By design for [PCI Compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) you cannot access the data entered in Stripe Elements. You can explore the "API Direct" option for handling the card data through your own form, but you will need to provide Stripe with PCI documentation.